# Zookeeper: Promoting changes to different development environments

Tags: apache-zookeeper, liquibase

I'm reviewing Zookeeper and would like to initially use it as a configuration service.

The one problem that comes to mind is... promoting changes across development environments.

i.e. DEV to QA to STAGING and finally Production.

In the past i would have used liquibase with some host specific configuration and pushed changes with patches/builds... but since Zookeeper doesn't have a relational database that won't work.

Are there any best practices, links or guidelines on how one is supposed to support a SDLC?
What am i missing?